# Automatically check the “Remember me” box on woocommerce login form?

Tags: woocommerce

how can i Automatically check the “Remember me” box on woocommerce login form?

```
                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form' ); ?>

                <p class="form-row">
                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-login' ); ?>
                    <input type="submit" class="button" name="login" value="<?php _e( 'Login', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
                    <label for="rememberme" class="inline">
                        <input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" /> <?php _e( 'Remember me', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                    </label>
                </p>
                <p class="lost_password">
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_lostpassword_url() ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Lost your password?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
                </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `checked="checked"`

```
<input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" checked="checked" />
```